# I have customrecord in which I have to set value of status to approved. I have used record.setValue, it is changing in the log but not in the record

Tags: netsuite, user-event

var currentStatus = reversalRecord.getValue({
fieldId: 'status'
});
log.debug('Current Status before Set:', currentStatus);

```
                reversalRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'status',
                    value: "Approved"
                }); 

                // Log status after setting
                var newStatus = reversalRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'status'
                });
                log.debug('New Status after Set:', newStatus);
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Are you calling `reversalRecord.save()` after setting the value?

Answer (score 0):

If that's a Journal Entry that you are saving you need to set the field 'approved' to `true`

Answer (score 0):

In NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0, if you're using record.setValue to update a field in a custom record, you also need to commit the changes using the record.save() method to persist the changes to the database.

/**

- @NApiVersion 2.x
- @NScriptType Suitelet
  */
  define(['N/record', 'N/log'], function(record, log) {

  function onRequest(context) {
  try {
  // Replace 'customrecord_your_custom_record_id' with the actual internal ID of your custom record type
  var customRecordId = 'customrecord_your_custom_record_id';

  ```
       // Replace 'your_custom_record_field_id' with the actual internal ID of the 'status' field in your custom record
       var statusFieldId = 'your_custom_record_field_id';

       // Replace 'your_custom_record_id' with the actual internal ID of the specific record you want to update
       var customRecordInstance = record.load({
           type: customRecordId,
           id: 'your_custom_record_id',
           isDynamic: true,
       });

       // Set the 'status' field value to 'approved'
       customRecordInstance.setValue({
           fieldId: statusFieldId,
           value: 'approved',
       });

       // Save the changes to the custom record
       var recordId = customRecordInstance.save();

       log.debug({
           title: 'Record Updated',
           details: 'Custom Record ID: ' + recordId,
       });

       context.response.write('Record Updated Successfully');
   } catch (e) {
       log.error({
           title: 'Error',
           details: e.toString(),
       });

       context.response.write('Error updating record: ' + e.message);
   }
  ```

  }

  return {
  onRequest: onRequest,
  };
  });